# Prestashop Show White Page When Using jquery multiple css method

Tags: php, jquery, css, prestashop-1.5

I used some piece of jquery codes **in prestashop 1.5** home page ,actually in Header.TPL file.

**when i use multiple css method** ( multiple in one line) , site doesn't load and **white page** will show on ( like when we have PHP syntax error ) .

**this are the codes :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#items li").hover(function(){

            $(this).children('a').css({"bottom":"0px","line-height":"120px","font-size":"25px"});

                },function(){

            $(this).children('a').css({"line-height":"25px","bottom":"-110px","font-size":"12px"});

     });
});
```

**but this method works as well :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#items li").hover(function(){

            $(this).children('a').css("bottom", "0px");
            $(this).children('a').css("font-size", "25px");
            $(this).children('a').css("line-height", "120px");
                },function(){
            $(this).children('a').css("bottom", "-110px");
            $(this).children('a').css("font-size", "12px");
            $(this).children('a').css("line-height", "25px");
     });
});
```

any suggestion will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Because of prestashop used Smarty for their templates, you can't use left and right braces at one line. But you can use {redelim} for a left curly brace ({), and {rdelim} for a right curly brace (}).

The easiest solution is to insert line breaks after braces. This code should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#items li").hover(function(){

        $(this).children('a').css({
       "bottom":"0px","line-height":"120px","font-size":"25px"
        });

            },function(){

        $(this).children('a').css({
           "line-height":"25px","bottom":"-110px","font-size":"12px"
        });

 });
});
```